# TeXnicCenter not working with Acrobat Reader

Tags: pdf, output, adobe, acrobat

Even after updating to R20 in the PDF section, TeXnicCenter is not opening Acrobat Reader. I'm using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version 2020.013.20074. The old trick does not seem to work.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Acrobat Reader is not recommended for use with latex documents: it locks the .pdfs, and before you can re-compile, you have to close the resulting .pdf.

Comment: Try with a lower case V: `AcroviewR20`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the Acrobat Pro DC version 21 (not acrobat reader). In order to find the version of the server I looked at the following registry entry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \Software\Classes\acrobat\shell\open\ddeexec\application

In my case I found that the server was AcroViewA21. Also in my case the executable that I was calling was the "Acrobat.exe", and not the "AcroRd32.exe".

It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm the previous answer, after my Adobe Acrobat automatically updated to 64 bit my TeXnicCenter failed to view - it hung. I changed the viewer comand line to that which appears in the Adobe icon properties target, which uses Acrobat.exe rather than AcroRd32.exe. This still failed to view, but did when I changed the viewer from AcroViewR21 to AcroViewA21 as suggested in Answer 1. Thank you very much Answer 1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

New version of Adobe Reader was released and new server version is required.

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC
Continuous Release Version 2022.001.20085 64Bit
Executable: Acrobat.exe

Server version: AcroViewA22