# Texnic Center, Error with pdf

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, output

I am facing the same problem as mentioned in [TeXnicCenter not working with Acrobat Reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579022/texniccenter-not-working-with-acrobat-reader)

Basically, when I want to generate pdf output, I get the following error:
[image]

I have tried updating the Build-Define Output profiles based on the following

[image]

But it still does not work. Could you please help?

Comment: do you have adobe pro? then the dde name should probably be `AcroviewA21`, for reader you need `AcroviewR21`.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC
Continuous Release | Version 2021.011.20039 | 64-bit

Comment: I tried AcroviewR21 and AcroviewA21 and it give me error.  I even tried different cases (upper, lower, etc)

Comment: I have a different version, my acrobat is 32 bit, so sorry I can't test.